# Machine learning com {tidymodels}

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidyverse

## Problematização

Estou tentando realizar uma tarefa de *machine learning* com {tidymodels} com a seguinte [base de dados](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cordeiroitamar/ml_wine/main/winequality-red.csv).

Trata-se de uma base com as características de vinhos. Entre as variáveis, há uma chamada `quality` que apresenta uma nota de 3 a 8. Minha intenção é criar um modelo capaz de classificar um vinho como "bom" (`quality` >=5) ou "ruim" (`quality` < 5)

---

## Problema

O modelo só prevê **um único tipo** de categoria.

---

## Carregamento das bibliotecas

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rio)
library(tidymodels)
library(janitor)
library(naniar)
```

---

## Importação da base

Importo a base e "limpo" os nomes

```
vinhos_raw <- 
  import("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cordeiroitamar/ml_wine/main/winequality-red.csv", setclass = "tibble") %>% 
  clean_names()

# A tibble: 6 × 12
  fixed_acidity volat…¹ citri…² resid…³ chlor…⁴ free_…⁵ total…⁶ density   p_h sulph…⁷
          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1           7.4    0.7     0        1.9   0.076      11      34   0.998  3.51    0.56
2           7.8    0.88    0        2.6   0.098      25      67   0.997  3.2     0.68
3           7.8    0.76    0.04     2.3   0.092      15      54   0.997  3.26    0.65
4          11.2    0.28    0.56     1.9   0.075      17      60   0.998  3.16    0.58
5           7.4    0.7     0        1.9   0.076      11      34   0.998  3.51    0.56
6           7.4    0.66    0        1.8   0.075      13      40   0.998  3.51    0.56
# … with 2 more variables: alcohol <dbl>, quality <int>, and abbreviated variable
#   names ¹​volatile_acidity, ²​citric_acid, ³​residual_sugar, ⁴​chlorides,
#   ⁵​free_sulfur_dioxide, ⁶​total_sulfur_dioxide, ⁷​sulphates
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

confiro se há valores `NA` e verificou que **não há**

```
vinhos_raw %>% 
  miss_var_summary()

# A tibble: 12 × 3
   variable             n_miss pct_miss
   <chr>                 <int>    <dbl>
 1 fixed_acidity             0        0
 2 volatile_acidity          0        0
 3 citric_acid               0        0
 4 residual_sugar            0        0
 5 chlorides                 0        0
 6 free_sulfur_dioxide       0        0
 7 total_sulfur_dioxide      0        0
 8 density                   0        0
 9 p_h                       0        0
10 sulphates                 0        0
11 alcohol                   0        0
12 quality                   0        0
```

e dou uma olhada geral na base

```
vinhos_raw %>% 
  glimpse()


Rows: 1,599
Columns: 12
$ fixed_acidity        <dbl> 7.4, 7.8, 7.8, 11.2, 7.4, 7.4, 7.9, 7.3, 7.8, 7.5, 6.7…
$ volatile_acidity     <dbl> 0.700, 0.880, 0.760, 0.280, 0.700, 0.660, 0.600, 0.650…
$ citric_acid          <dbl> 0.00, 0.00, 0.04, 0.56, 0.00, 0.00, 0.06, 0.00, 0.02, …
$ residual_sugar       <dbl> 1.9, 2.6, 2.3, 1.9, 1.9, 1.8, 1.6, 1.2, 2.0, 6.1, 1.8,…
$ chlorides            <dbl> 0.076, 0.098, 0.092, 0.075, 0.076, 0.075, 0.069, 0.065…
$ free_sulfur_dioxide  <dbl> 11, 25, 15, 17, 11, 13, 15, 15, 9, 17, 15, 17, 16, 9, …
$ total_sulfur_dioxide <dbl> 34, 67, 54, 60, 34, 40, 59, 21, 18, 102, 65, 102, 59, …
$ density              <dbl> 0.9978, 0.9968, 0.9970, 0.9980, 0.9978, 0.9978, 0.9964…
$ p_h                  <dbl> 3.51, 3.20, 3.26, 3.16, 3.51, 3.51, 3.30, 3.39, 3.36, …
$ sulphates            <dbl> 0.56, 0.68, 0.65, 0.58, 0.56, 0.56, 0.46, 0.47, 0.57, …
$ alcohol              <dbl> 9.4, 9.8, 9.8, 9.8, 9.4, 9.4, 9.4, 10.0, 9.5, 10.5, 9.…
$ quality              <int> 5, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, …
```

Como a intenção e é que a variável-alvo (`quality`) seja classificada como "bom" (qualidade >=5) ou "ruim" (qualidade < 5), realizo uma transformação nesta variável:

```
vinhos <- 
  vinhos_raw %>% 
  mutate(quality = if_else(condition = quality >=5,
                           true = "bom",
                           false = "ruim"),
         quality = as.factor(quality)) %>% 
  select(quality, everything())
```

Checo como ficou:

```
vinhos %>% 
  head()


# A tibble: 6 × 12
  quality fixed_acidity volat…¹ citri…² resid…³ chlor…⁴ free_…⁵ total…⁶ density   p_h
  <fct>           <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 bom               7.4    0.7     0        1.9   0.076      11      34   0.998  3.51
2 bom               7.8    0.88    0        2.6   0.098      25      67   0.997  3.2 
3 bom               7.8    0.76    0.04     2.3   0.092      15      54   0.997  3.26
4 bom              11.2    0.28    0.56     1.9   0.075      17      60   0.998  3.16
5 bom               7.4    0.7     0        1.9   0.076      11      34   0.998  3.51
6 bom               7.4    0.66    0        1.8   0.075      13      40   0.998  3.51
# … with 2 more variables: sulphates <dbl>, alcohol <dbl>, and abbreviated variable
#   names ¹​volatile_acidity, ²​citric_acid, ³​residual_sugar, ⁴​chlorides,
#   ⁵​free_sulfur_dioxide, ⁶​total_sulfur_dioxide
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

---

## Split do dataset

Faço o split do dataset com `initial_split()` usando a proporção padrão da função (`prop = 3/4`) e colocando no `strata =`  a variável `quality`

```
vinhos_split <- initial_split(vinhos, strata = quality)
```

### Criação do dataset de **TREINO**

```
vinhos_treino <- training(vinhos_split)
```

### Criação do dataset de **TESTE**

```
vinhos_teste <- testing(vinhos_split)
```

---

## Criação dos modelos

Como se trata de um problema de **classificação**, escolho dois modelos para testar qual performa melhor:

1. random forest
2. regressão logística

### Criação do modelo: *RANDOM FOREST*

```
vinhos_model_rand_forest <- 
  rand_forest() %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")
```

### Criação do modelo: *REGRESSAO LOGISTICA*

```
vinhos_model_logistic_reg <- 
  logistic_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("glm") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")
```

---

## Confecção da **receita**

Para a receita:

- defini `quality` como variável-alvo e as demais como variáveis preditoras;
- apliquei o passo de retirar variáveis preditoras que tenham variância zero (`step_zv()`)
- apliquei o passo de normalizar todas as variáveis preditoras (`step_normalize()`)

```
vinhos_recipe <- 
  recipe(quality ~., data=vinhos_treino) %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())
```

---

## Criação do workflow

### Criação do workflow *RANDOM FOREST*

```
vinhos_wf_random_forest <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(vinhos_model_rand_forest) %>% 
  add_recipe(vinhos_recipe)
```

### Criação do workflow *REGRESSÃO LOGÍSTICA*

```
vinhos_wf_logistic_regression <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(vinhos_model_logistic_reg) %>% 
  add_recipe(vinhos_recipe)
```

---

## Realização da validação cruzada

Para a validação cruzada, usei o dataset de **TREINO**, com **10** folds e com a variável `quality` no `strata =` .

```
vinhos_cross_validation <- 
  vfold_cv(data = vinhos_treino, 
           v = 10, 
           strata = quality)
```

### Reamostragem para o modelo *RANDOM FOREST*

```
vinhos_fit_resamples_random_forest <- 
  fit_resamples(object = vinhos_wf_random_forest,
                resample = vinhos_cross_validation,
                metrics = metric_set(accuracy))
```

### Reamostragem para o modelo *REGRESSÃO LOGÍSTICA*

```
vinhos_fit_resamples_logistic_regression <- 
  fit_resamples(object = vinhos_wf_logistic_regression,
                resample = vinhos_cross_validation,
                metrics = metric_set(accuracy))
```

### Comparação da acurácia dos modelos

Acurácia do modelo *RANDON FOREST*:

```
vinhos_fit_resamples_random_forest %>% 
  collect_metrics()

# A tibble: 1 × 6
  .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config             
  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
1 accuracy binary     0.959    10 0.00457 Preprocessor1_Model1
```

Acurácia do modelo *REGRESSÃO LOGÍSTICA*:

```
vinhos_fit_resamples_logistic_regression %>% 
  collect_metrics()

# A tibble: 1 × 6
  .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config             
  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
1 accuracy binary     0.962    10 0.00452 Preprocessor1_Model1
```

Aparentemente tem algo errado pois a acurácia está extremamente alta: **96%** em ambos os modelos
De qualquer forma, como é preciso escolher um modelo para seguir em frente: vou escolher o *RANDOM FOREST*.

---

## Last fit

Para o **last fit** uso o dataset de **TESTE**

```
vinhos_last_fit_random_forest <- 
  last_fit(vinhos_wf_random_forest,
           vinhos_teste,
           split = vinhos_split,
           metrics = metric_set(accuracy))
```

### Coleto as métricas do *last fit*

```
vinhos_last_fit_random_forest %>% 
  collect_metrics()

# A tibble: 1 × 4
  .metric  .estimator .estimate .config             
  <chr>    <chr>          <dbl> <chr>               
1 accuracy binary         0.962 Preprocessor1_Model1
```

Novamente: acurácia muito alta.
Provavelmente, há algo errado!

### Coleto as previsões do *last fit*

```
vinhos_last_fit_random_forest %>% 
  collect_predictions()

# A tibble: 400 × 5
   id               .pred_class  .row quality .config             
   <chr>            <fct>       <int> <fct>   <chr>               
 1 train/test split bom             2 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
 2 train/test split bom            13 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
 3 train/test split bom            22 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
 4 train/test split bom            31 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
 5 train/test split bom            35 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
 6 train/test split bom            43 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
 7 train/test split bom            44 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
 8 train/test split bom            51 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
 9 train/test split bom            56 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
10 train/test split bom            61 bom     Preprocessor1_Model1
# … with 390 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

---

## Confusion matrix do last fit

Conforme se verifica na *confusion matrix* abaixo, o modelo não acertou nenhum "ruim".
É como se o modelo só soubesse classificar como "bom"

```
vinhos_last_fit_random_forest %>% 
  collect_predictions() %>% 
  conf_mat(truth = quality, 
           estimate = .pred_class) %>% 
  autoplot(type = "heatmap")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu filtrar os vinhos classificados como ruim no dataset original, veremos que o modelo classificou todos como "bom"

```
vinhos_last_fit_random_forest %>% 
  collect_predictions() %>% 
  filter(quality == "ruim")

# A tibble: 16 × 2
   quality .pred_class
   <fct>   <fct>      
 1 ruim    bom       
 2 ruim    bom        
 3 ruim    bom        
 4 ruim    bom        
 5 ruim    bom        
 6 ruim    bom        
 7 ruim    bom        
 8 ruim    bom        
 9 ruim    bom       
10 ruim    bom        
11 ruim    bom        
12 ruim    bom        
13 ruim    bom        
14 ruim    bom        
15 ruim    bom        
16 ruim    bom
```

---

## Questionamento

A minha dúvida é: em que parte(s) do processo eu cometi equívoco(s)?

---

## Nota: origem da base

A base é a base de qualidade de vinhos verdes tintos e brancos da [UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O modelo só consegue classificar como bom porque praticamente só há vinhos bons no teu conjunto de dados:

```r
vinhos |> 
   count(quality)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  quality     n
  <fct>   <int>
1 bom      1536
2 ruim       63
```

Ter usado a amostragem estratificada com o comando

```r
initial_split(vinhos, strata = quality)
```

só fez perpetuar essa desigualdade. Há duas sugestões que posso te dar aqui:

### Altere a definição de vinho bom e vinho ruim

Ao utilizar um limite de nota igual a 6 para definir se um vinho é bom ou não, as classes ficam bem mais equilibradas:

```r
vinhos <- 
  vinhos_raw %>% 
  mutate(quality = if_else(condition = quality >=6,
                           true = "bom",
                           false = "ruim"),
         quality = as.factor(quality)) %>% 
  select(quality, everything())

vinhos |> 
  count(quality)

# A tibble: 2 × 2
  quality     n
  <fct>   <int>
1 bom       855
2 ruim      744
```

### Deixe ambas as classes com o mesmo número de observações

Utilize o `themis::step_downsample` dentro da tua receita. Com isso, ambas as classes ficarão com o mesmo número de observações. Entretanto, isso pode não ser interessante no teu caso de `quality >= 5`, pois o tamanho amostral ficará pequeno demais, tanto para treino, quanto para teste.

### Bônus: por que uma acurácia alta pode ser ruim?

Imagine que desejamos detectar câncer em uma população. Para simplificar, temos 100 pessoas, das quais 99 são saudáveis e 1 tem câncer. Se criarmos o seguinte algoritmo:

```r
if (x == pessoa){
  return("não tem câncer")
```

ele vai ter acurácia de 99% em detectar quem é saudável, mesmo sendo um péssimo algoritmo. Minha sugestão é, além de calcular a matriz de confusão, como foi feito na pergunta, calcule também outras métricas. Para começar, sugiro sensitividade e especificidade, para detectar verdadeiros positivos e verdadeiros negativos, respectivamente.

Comment: Muito esclarecedor Marcus Nunes. Obrigado